# Demagnetization of pulse transformer megnetizing inductance

Tags: power-supply, transformer, analog, electromagnetism, magnetics

Here I am caculating the power dissipation in the primary of pulse transformer. The transformer has very small secondary current hence primary and secondary current are ignored.

My question is when voltage pulse (Vin) of 3 volts appers across the transformer, does current (Ilm) rises linearly during on time and current decreases linearly during off time as shown in the diagram?

Is the represenation of current (Ilm) waveform correct in the image?

Linear increase and decrese of slope ideally has to be same?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that you are charging the core with magnetic energy according to U=L(dI/dt)?

Comment: What matters is how you ensure opposite volt-seconds during the off-time to reset the core, provided there is no current in primary side during the on-time of course (transformer in series with the power switch). Usually a circuit featuring a Zener diode in the secondary is appropriate.

Comment: @Verbal Kint  During the off time of pulse , there is no primary current  then demagnetizing current will pass through  the input voltage  source  which is at zero volts ?  Kindly elaborate  where the demagnetize current will flow .

Comment: @winny  i will charge  core wirh 3volts and 1us pulse volts.time product.  During off time whats the path of demagnetize  current ? Is it through the input voltage supply ?

Comment: No, you ensure demagnetization via the secondary side that you let jump to a controlled value via a resistance or a Zener diode. Let me find some time and I'll write down a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Verbal Kint okay. Looking forward  to your comprehensive answer

Comment: Simulate it and see for yourself where the magnitizing current goes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concentrate on the magnetising current Ilm, the algebraic sum of primary and secondary current, then to first order, Ilm rises linearly during the on time due to the constant applied 3 V, as dI/dt = V/L. The main departure from linearity is due to the finite resistance of the primary. As the current increases, the voltage drop across this resistance reduces the available voltage for ramping Ilm, and the current rises more slowly later on in the pulse.

In the off time, the way Ilm falls is down to how you choose to reset the magnetisation in the core. You choose what voltage to apply, and the current will change accordingly. You can apply a voltage by letting the core drive current through a resistor, or a zener, or you can switch to a voltage source. Many people opt for a zener as (1) it's passive, so the current stops at zero (unlike switching to a specific voltage) and (2) it's faster than a resistor for the same peak voltage, as the voltage doesn't drop by much as the current falls.

Choose a flux reset voltage value so you reach zero current before the next pulse, under your worst case duty cycle conditions. It doesn't matter whether you reset the flux very quickly and spend a while at zero, or only just get to zero before the next pulse begins.

Comment: @Neil_UKunderstand . so i have to connect the zener diode between primary of the transformer  ( cathode of zener to + and anode  the - of input voltage supply Vin ) . so when inductor voltage kicks back during off period zener will regulate it to 3V and take  out all the energy stored in inductor.

Comment: If your duty cycle was 50%, then 3 V would just be sufficient. It would be prudent to use more than 3 V, to get the current down to zero with a comfortable margin before the next pulse began. I'm not going to comment on your word picture. Add a schematic of what you mean to your OP, use the board's inbuilt schematic editor.

Comment: right. to utilize more flux higher zener can be placed . please see the new schematic posted in the original question above . its for  CAN application.  comment on the connection of the zener diode in the primary .  thanks

Comment: That zener will clamp at 0.7v, it's the negative excursion you're clamping. You need it the other way round, in series with an ordinary diode to isolate the forward 3 V. The benefit of using the board's inbuilt schematic editor is that other people can copy it and edit it easily. Not sure what you mean about 'utilise more flux'. The flux is whatever you've got at the end of the 'on' pulse. A higher voltage reset will simply discharge it faster.

Comment: i could not find the option of schematic  editor and will explore it . I  mean by utilise more flux is   higher voltage  reset i can go upto 90 percent of duty  cycle. Thanks for ur detailed  explanation.

Comment: It's the very indistinct diode+capacitor+resistor icon to the right of the add picture mountains icon.